# Client side manipulation of MongoDB data without sending to server

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, mongodb, flask

I have a lot of GPS points that I need to play with in Google Maps. When loaded from JSON, the document is about 150MB. Google Maps can handle this fine.

A website I built lets a user select maybe 20-50 points and tag them with additional information. This needs to be sent to the server, the server does some processing, and sends back the GPS points again.

I'm looking for ways to speed up this application.

Unfortunately, sparsely sampling this data isn't a solution given our weird requirements.

I see two bottlenecks. One is the initial transfer to the client. My goal would be to do all processing locally and only push the 150MB back to the server when the processing is final. The other bottle neck is query time, which doesn't seem to take that long considering the transfer time.

Would using HTML5 local storage help with this at all? Is there another solution that would be better than this?

The way I currently have it set up:

1. Users visit a website.
2. That website requests JSON from another DB server that queries the MongoDB and provides a JSON response.
3. The browser downloads that JSON and plots the points on the map.

I'm thinking I could insert something between 2 and 3 that would write to local storage and let the user manipulate that stuff locally. But is there a better way?

More details: This is for an internal data curation tool that might be used by 4 people total in a building using LAN speeds. But it's still slow. Maybe 10 seconds per page load.

Comment: Regarding HTML5 local storage, the W3 recommends a mostly arbitrary limit of 5MB of data stored locally. Your solution is looking at 30 times that, so it's likely not a valid solution. http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#disk-space

Comment: Some other questions: How often does the data change? Could you load it to the client once a week? Does this have to be browser-based? Maybe a simple desktop app would work better?

Comment: MongoDB actually sends the data as BSON (binary version of JSON), which is much better compressed. Only the drivers on the client side decode it to regular JSON. Do you need to go through the "other" DB server or could you query MongoDB directly from the website application?